# key vault secrets based on the role

Tags: azure-keyvault

we have many secrets in Azure key vault. what we want is a few of the secrets to be visible based on the role. Is it possible?

I can give overall access to secrets based on Access control (IAM)
(like reader/writer) etc. How can I make sure a few of secrets should not be visible to a particular role.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible right now.  Access to an object is either all-or-nothing.